# Image uploading not happening after using dragging code

Tags: javascript, draggable, image-uploading

In this [Codepen1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNJeLa) : , i am uploading one image inside another....

In this [Codepen2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqmRyV), i can able to drag one image  inside another....

Now I am trying combine both features , to upload & drag one image inside another, but uploading is not happening  in [codepen3](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exvRqG)

**Html**

```
<input type="file" onchange="load(this.files[0])"/><br>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="324" height="395">

    <mask id="mask1">
        <image style="background-color:green;" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5daY.png" width="324" height="395"></image>
    </mask>

<div class="minaimg masked-img" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" onwheel="scrollZoom(event)">
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" id="uploadedImg">
<div class = "minaimg" >

<image id="masked-image" xlink:href="" mask="url(#mask1)"></image>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</svg>
```

**script**

```
function load(file) {
    var img = new Image(),
        imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);


    img.onload = function() {
        var width = img.naturalWidth,
            height = img.naturalHeight,
            maskedImage = document.getElementById('masked-image');

        maskedImage.setAttribute('xlink:href', imgURL);
        maskedImage.setAttribute('height', 395);


        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            translateX = 0,
            translateY = 0,
            scale = 1,
            zoomFactor = 0.1;

        function onDragStart(evt) {
            if (evt.dataTransfer && evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage) {
                evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(evt.target.nextElementSibling, 0, 0);
            }
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
        }

        function onDragOver(evt) {
            translateX += evt.clientX - prevX;
            translateY += evt.clientY - prevY;
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
            updateStyle();
        }

        function updateStyle() {
            let transform = "translate(" + translateX + "px, " + translateY + "px) scale(" + scale + ")";
            if (document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img')) document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img').style.transform = transform;
        }


        URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
    };

    img.src = imgURL;




}
```

Please let me know if you have any other doubts....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: So what you want is to be able to change the tchuk-tchuk image from codepen2 to one you'd select on your hard-drive?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for reply , no , may be i didt posted requirement correctly.... `In codepen1 , i want to drag the inner image similar like codepen2` , you can try dragging image in codepen2

Comment: you can able to drag image in codepen2, but not happening in codepen1, so i want to drag image in codepen1 , thats all.....

Comment: Yeah, well that you are able to drag in codepen1 or able to upload in codepen2, I don't see the difference. Can you explain better then?

Comment: i can able to `upload` in codepen1, but i `cant able to drag` ..... but in codepen2, i can able to `drag` , so i want to drag in codepen1 also......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display an image from user's disk is just a matter of creating an URL pointing to it, and to set an <img> tag's `src` pointing to this URL.

Youapparently know how to do it with *URL.createObjectURL*.

In your draggable version, you already have such an <img> element, so you just need to set its `src` in the input's *onchange* event:

```js
fileup.onchange = e => {
 target_img.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]);   
}

///Below is OP's code\\\


let prevX = 0, prevY = 0,translateX = 0, translateY = 0, scale = 1, zoomFactor = 0.1;
//const img = document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img');

function onDragStart(evt) {
  if (evt.dataTransfer && evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage) {
evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(evt.target.nextElementSibling, 0, 0);
  }
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
}

function onDragOver(evt) {
  translateX += evt.clientX - prevX;
  translateY += evt.clientY - prevY;
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
  updateStyle();
}

function updateStyle() 
{ 
let transform = "translate(" +translateX+ "px, "+ translateY + "px) scale("+scale+")"; 
if(document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img'))document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img').style.transform = transform;
}
```

```css
.masked-img {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpM4.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpM4.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  bottom:60px;
  left:40px;
}


.minaimg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileup" />
<div class="minaimg masked-img" ondragover="onDragOver(event)" >
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" id="uploadedImg">
    <div class="minaimg">
      <!-- give an id for ease of selection -->
      <img id="target_img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV6yq.jpg" alt="">

      <div></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, you are already displaying the image before selecting, but image should display only after i choose file..... please update the code......

Comment: You can update the code yourself! Just remove the src attribute from the HTML markup.

Comment: sorry for delay, I did't observed that in a hurry .... your solution is working fine.....